# How to connect MySQL DB with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: mysql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-express

The last 2 weeks I've been struggling trying to set up a simple ASP.NET MVC 4 Project where I can connect to my MySQL Database (hosted by my website provider).
Because I am a student and beginning with ASP.NET MVC 4 and don't want any costs, so I downloaded, installed and now am developing in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.
I've read various blogs and step-by-step manuals on how to set up e.g. a MVC 3 Project with MySQL connection in VSE '12, or create a Microsoft Azure MySQL DB and connect to that DB, tried various MySQL DB Connector versions and EF versions but all in all: Nothing worked with me at all!

So, to make a long story short: What I'm looking for is a very simple step-by-step manual on how to create a ASP.NET MVC 4 Project in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and connect to my MySQL Database (of course from my Windows 8 computer), with all appending references and connectors, which have to be preinstalled.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What you need is a connector as by default VS does not know how to connect to MySQL. If you search for 'mysql vs2013 connector' you will find links to the software required and how to install.

Comment: I even suggest to give some thing which you have tried, and if any errors you are getting, post them too, so that we can able to help you from there